# Custom message when wordpress updates are available

Tags: updates

Just a quick question to see if anyone has done this before, is there a function that I can use to add a custom message to the "Wordpress XX is available"

[image: Update Notice Image]

Recently, I've had clients updating their own site and making a right mess of things, especially with third party plugins.

I just want to throw a notification on saying how updating could cause issues, please contact me first.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove it completely?

You can add this to your themes functions.php file:

```
// Hide update notice for everyone except admins
function wps_hide_update_notice() {
            if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
                remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
            }
        }

add_action('admin_menu','wps_hide_update_notice');
```

Comment: Because it's nice to have the client aware that their site needs updating. I just want to give them the ability to tell me, rather than update it themselves. I've had a client recently press update on all plugins, and one in particular (woocommerce) has rewritten its core files, so the template had broken and needed to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no filter to customize the message for available updates, you need first to remove that message and display yours:

- Remove actions that will display the update notifications:

  ```
  function hide_original_update_notice() 
  {
          remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
          remove_action( 'network_admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
  }
  add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_original_update_notice', 1 );
  ```
- Create your notification action:

  ```
  function my_custom_update_nag() {
          if ( is_multisite() && !current_user_can('update_core') )
                  return false;

          global $pagenow;

          if ( 'update-core.php' == $pagenow )
                  return;

          $cur = get_preferred_from_update_core();

          if ( ! isset( $cur->response ) || $cur->response != 'upgrade' )
                  return false;

          if ( current_user_can('update_core') ) {
                  $msg = sprintf( __('<a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_%1$s">WordPress %1$s</a> is available! <a href="%2$s">Please update now</a>.'), $cur->current, network_admin_url( 'update-core.php' ) );
          } else {
                  $msg = sprintf( __('<a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_%1$s">WordPress %1$s</a> is available! Please notify the site administrator.'), $cur->current );
          }
          echo "<div class='update-nag'>$msg</div>";
  }
  add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_custom_update_nag', 3 );
  add_action( 'network_admin_notices', 'my_custom_update_nag', 3 );
  ```

Comment: This is fantastic, However, it doesn't seem to want to remove the previous message, no matter how I use remove_action. Is it being removed when you do it on 3.9.1?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus i have updated my answer with the complete solution